# How to update freefilesync

Tags: updates

I have installed freefilesynk via and then the Download "freefilesync" 64-Bit option:

[Download freefilesync](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/vivid/apps/getdeb/freefilesync)

It is a great tool and I think it may even replace the Luckybackup I have installed.

It is asking my to update, but when I try, it just downloads a number of files. Can anyone help me update this app to the latest version freefilesync 7.1?

Comment: refer [here](http://www.freefilesync.org/faq.php#uninstall)

Comment: For which Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 3):

The newest version, as can be seen on the [official site](http://www.freefilesync.org/download.php) is 7.6. To update you just have to extract the new version over the old directory.

A better way to install and update freefilesync, would be to use the official ppa. This way you always have a version that is compatible with your current Ubuntu version.

https://launchpad.net/~freefilesync/+archive/ubuntu/ffs

The process for installing the ppa is standard and described on the site I linked.

As of November 2015 the ppa is up to date, again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Ubuntu 14.04 (or earlier) the most easy way is to use the [Freefilesync PPA](https://launchpad.net/~freefilesync/+archive/ubuntu/ffs) :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs
sudo apt-get update
```

With this PPA FreeFileSync will automatically be updated when you run `sudo apt-get upgrade` (or when starting the Update Manager).

See here : [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) for more information about PPAs.

Comment: The PPA is not longer maintained.

Comment: Indeed. I have updated my answer thanks for the notice.